# Javascript variable undefined even though I can see the value I'm trying to capture on the screen

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I have the following data in a table:

```
<tr>
  <td><strong><center><a href="#modalDrillDown" role="button" onclick="defineSelectedSector('Automotive')" data-toggle="modal">Automotive</a></center></strong></td>
  <td><center id="automotiveCurrentQ"></center></td>
  <td><center id="automotiveCurrentQ1"></center></td>
  <td><center id="automotiveCurrentQ2"></center></td>
  <td><center id="automotiveCurrentQ3"></center></td>
  <td><center id="automotiveCurrentQ4"></center></td>
</tr>
```

The values are set by another js file and this part works fine. My problem is that when I click on the link I need to carry this values forward to a new set of values. So inside the"defineSelectedSector" function I have said:

```
document.getElementById('drill1Current').innerText=document.getElementById('automotiveCurrentQ').value;
```

I have tried this a few ways round and it always returns that is is undefined even though I can see the value 'automotiveCurrentQ' on the screen and via inspect element.

What am I missing?

Thanks again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it always returns that is is undefined"? What exactly is undefined?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can see the value 'automotiveCurrentQ' on the screen"?

Comment: You're going to need to post the actual code involved.

Comment: **there's no value inside** `<td><center id="automotiveCurrentQ"></center></td>:`

Comment: I am using bootstrap modals to display the data. So the first table shows all sectors in a region. When you click the link it opens a new modal on top that has uk average for the sector and I also need it to show that data from the table row shown but when I try to capture it using the second bit of code all the table values come up as undefined

Comment: You are using `value` on a non-input element.

Comment: You should use document.getElementById('automotiveCurrentQ').textContent;

Comment: The value inside "automotiveCurrentQ" is defined via the onclick that opens that first modal

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
document.getElementById('automotiveCurrentQ')***.textContent***;

instead of

document.getElementById('automotiveCurrentQ')***.value***;

Answer (score 0):

Try using `textContent` instead of `value` or `innerText`:

```
document.getElementById('drill1Current').textContent = document.getElementById('automotiveCurrentQ').textContent;
```

Also, in your example the table didn't have any contents. Make sure the script that enters the data is run before the snippet above.

Obligatory JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbqLsotv/